# Screen brightness increase and decrease keys inoperative

Tags: brightness, keys, dead-keys

Screen brightness increase and decrease keys inoperative

On notebook Lenovo:
Family: IdeaPad 3 15ITL6
Press increases and decreases brigthness directly on the keyboard.
But on Ubuntu 5.19.0-23-generic keys are inoperative.
VERSION="22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)"

Command output
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland

Following is the information of the output of lspci:
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

Strange that in the directory there is no information about the Intel driver:

ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K out 20 04:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K out 20 04:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 ago 19 02:16 10-amdgpu.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,4K set 14 06:59 10-quirks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 jul  8 06:52 10-radeon.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,4K fev 11  2022 40-libinput.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3,4K abr  6  2022 70-wacom.conf

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running wayland or X-server? (Wayland is default since 20.04)

Comment: You have given the kernel number good to know but what is the version of Ubuntu also good to know.

Comment: VERSION="22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)"

Comment: Command output
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland